# Character Overflow™ on profile page with long usernames

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, display-names

I changed my username recently, to one I've used a long time in the past.

Out of curiosity, I decided to look at how it's showing in my profile page, and it seems to be overflowing under the weight of the "top %" indicator:

> [image: "Hedgeho" and "g" on another line]

For clarity, this is how it looks like with another username of the same length, but with characters that take up less width:

> [image: No overflow]

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: This feels [tag:status-bydesign]. What are you suggesting be done with user names that still don't fit? As it stands, changing the font system wide would only accommodate your username and maybe a few others. I'm not sure this is a bug, but making the font marginally smaller doesn't seem like a viable solution to names that exceed the available length.

Comment: @RobertCartaino It used to work back when I wasn't a top user of this site. Maybe removing the "top %" indicator on long usernames would fix it (it's still shown in the activity tab)?

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Better word-wrapping would seem to be the only good way to handle this.

Comment: Sonic, There are other "indicators" that can cause the name to wrap even though they once fit (becoming a moderator, for example). So there would need to be a more significant redesign/layout to accommodate everything that might cause a name to be crowded out. Hrm. Outside my area, so I'll have to leave it at that.

Comment: 1. I find users who choose a *long* string of numbers and random letters as their username to be, strangely, egotistical. They are not looking to blend into the crowd but to stand out. Similarly, usernames which are unnecessarily long, like yours, although easy enough to remember they take an awful amount of space when users want to ping them. Yes. You told me that "Sonic" by itself was enough and that's what I did,…

Comment: 2....I [pinged you using @Sonic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316929/small-nitpicky-edits-to-grammar-punctuation-and-capitalization-feel-really-pa/316931#comment1039081_316931) but you didn't reply. So there's no shortcut, one has to write out the full username. As for fixing this very minor inconvenience on your profile page, may I suggest you shorten your username by one character?

Comment: 3. I'm puzzled, is the ™ necessary every time we mention Overflow in our posts. Say it ain't so, or we'll get enthusiastic users editing and bumping ten-year-posts again. Arggghhhhhh :)

Comment: @RobertCartaino fixing this is as easy as removing [this CSS rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd5c0.png) from that specific container. Result of removing the rule: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFVOB.png

Comment: @Mari pinging does not mean the pinged user must reply. Sonic got your ping as inbox item. The shortcut works, believe me. As for ™ it's a rather new meme added for design bugs, I don't use it myself but it became a fact and to be honest, quite funny. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I got the notification; I was busy at the time so I didn't reply. It does work; typing the first three characters of the username will work according to the FAQ on comment @-replies. Also, regarding the title, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316142/377214).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always true that the OP's lengthy username gets cut short. On three separate occasions when I have clicked on the user's name on the main page, I have seen the username perfectly formatted. The first time I thought the bug had been fixed but when I clicked again, the username spilled over.

So, I have managed to take screenshots of the last two instances. I don't know why, and I cannot figure how to replicate this fluke but it happens and I had to wait until today before I could get the third screenshot.

2nd time, 26th October

> [image]
>
> [image]

and just now it has happened again, you can tell the screenshots were taken later if you look at the number of profile views, and the rep the OP has since earned

3rd time, 28th October

> [image]
>
> [image]

**UPDATE**

It's fixed. I didn't do anything but it got fixed. The username does not get cut off when the ratings in the blue box appear.

In order to be certain that the inconvenience was fixed, I looked for usernames longer than 26 characters but failed to find any. It seems to have been an isolated case but was resolved relatively quickly.

> [image]

Comment: The "top 0.18% this year" disappears and re-appears for some reason. It's only when it appears that it gets cut off.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I can't seem to reproduce it at will, I have no idea why this happens.